# gnuplot under windows: how to specify window size/position when it startup?

Tags: windows, gnuplot

Under windows 10, how can I specify window postion (X,Y) and window size (width,height) of gnuplot, via command line arguments?

The path of the application is

```
D:\gnuplot\bin\wgnuplot.exe
```

how can specify window postion and size with it? like with cygwin mintty:

```
D:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico 
   -p 372,12 -s 135,50 -o Font=Consolas -o FontHeight=13 -
```

`show version long` output

```
    Version 5.2 patchlevel 0    last modified 2017-09-01
Compile options:
    +READLINE  -LIBREADLINE  +HISTORY  
    -BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY  +UNICODE  +OBJECTS  +STATS +EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS 
    +LIBCERF  +GD_PNG  +GD_JPEG  +GD_TTF  +GD_GIF  +ANIMATION  
    -USE_CWDRC  +USE_MOUSE  +HIDDEN3D_QUADTREE  
    MAX_PARALLEL_AXES=13
```

P.S.
I mean the window of gnuplot, not the graph it plots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gnuplot under Windows 10 can use an init file `wgnuplot.ini` which is located at %AppData% (C:\Users\maij\AppData\Roaming in my case).

You can generate and update the file by clicking the upper left icon of the gnuplot window and following "Options -> Update wgnuplot.ini" (see the following picture). Please play a bit with window positions and sizes and updating the ini file to see how it works.

[image: update wgnuplot.ini]

My suggestion would be to generate `wgnuplot.ini` with the appropriate entries before launching gnuplot.

Currently my wgnuplot.ini looks as follows:

```
[WGNUPLOT]
TextOrigin=290 50
TextSize=785 489
TextMinimized=0
TextMaximized=0
TextFont=Consolas,9
TextWrap=1
TextLines=400
SysColors=0
DockVerticalTextFrac=350
DockHorizontalTextFrac=400
```

`TextOrigin` and `TextSize` are the options you are interested in.