# How to have GNUPlot open several Plots windows in Cascade Format

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I have a C++ console program that calls GNUPlot for plotting data.  It was working like a dream with numerous plot windows being plotted "cascade" style but now for no apparent reason when I run the console program GNUPlot windows are opened directly superimposed on each other so I have to manually separate them out.  Is this a WIN 10 issue or a GNUPlot issue or even a VS2019 Console issue?  I have not changed any of the GNUPlot settings (knowingly) and can see no way within GNUPlot 5.2 patchlevel 7 to restore the cascading.  The only stuff I can find for WIN 10 is a cascade function on the Task Bar but this only refers to windows already open and is no help.

Comment: Does updating the `wgnuplot.ini` file help?
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47083791/1458097

Comment: Thanks heap: you were right.  I've posted an answer to the original problem: I appreciate your prompt advice!

Answer (score 0):

Hooray! Thanks a million heap!  I found that deleting the gnuplot.ini file restored the cascading of windows.  Then I found that restoring the gnuplot.ini file but commenting out the offending line cured the problem: thus #GraphOrigin=36 198.  Interestingly, the  gnuplot_history file in the same folder recorded "cascadingcascadingcascading."